# dragStart, dragEnd in Android Google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a problem to detect when the camera is moving and when it's stop. I found a workaround on google code (http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4636).

But, for me, the workaround did not work as i want. In the callback, i have :

```
gMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            if (!mMapIsTouched)
                Log.d("DEBUG", Map is not touched);
            else
                Log.d("DEBUG", Map is touched);
    }
};
```

In the logs, when the user put off his finger, i have "Map is touched" which is the last log and in other cases, it's ok.